# variable name is appended to json instead of variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I get a json from an API I wrote. This json contains some values and one of this should be appended to another json. 
The json to append the data to is the following:

```
originalOrder = {
              "nome": 1,
              "cognome": 2,
              "mail": 3,
              "telefono": 4,
              "cf": 5,
              "data": 6,
              "ora": 7,
              "cellit": 8,
              "cellex": 9
          };
```

The data I need to append is:

```
var toAppend = data.name;
```

and if i echo the toAppend value it shows the correct value. Say for example that toAppend echoes dummyData. I want the json to be at the end:

```
originalOrder = {
              "nome": 1,
              "cognome": 2,
              "mail": 3,
              "telefono": 4,
              "cf": 5,
              "data": 6,
              "ora": 7,
              "cellit": 8,
              "cellex": 9,
              "dummyData": 10
          };
```

So I also calculate the length of the array:

```
var lunghezza = parseInt(originalOrder.length);
lunghezza = lunghezza +2;
```

and then I add the new item to the array:

```
originalOrder.toAppend=lunghezza;
```

but the array ends up like this:

```
originalOrder = {
                  "nome": 1,
                  "cognome": 2,
                  "mail": 3,
                  "telefono": 4,
                  "cf": 5,
                  "data": 6,
                  "ora": 7,
                  "cellit": 8,
                  "cellex": 9,
                  "toAppend": NaN
              };
```

so I have two issues:

- i get the variable name instead of the variable value
- I get not a number instead of 10 (I tried also to force it with parseInt but seems with no luck)

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit:
if I do

var toAppend = data.nome;
console.log('toAppend: '+toAppend);

in console.log:

> toAppend: dummyData;
>   that is the expected behaviour

Thanks!

Comment: originalOrder is an object (dictionary). And with objects if you use .length it will return undefined and if you add numbers to undefined it will always return NaN.

Comment: Can you show what `console.log` shows for `dummyData`? What are you trying to append exactly, if you are adding a property called `voce`, do you expect a different key to appear? Also, `originalOrder` is an object, not an array. It has no `length` property. If you want to count the keys in the object, use `Object.keys(originalOrder).length`

Comment: Once you correct the length issues as described in the earlier comments, `originalOrder[toAppend]=lunghezza;`

Comment: @casraf see my edit

Comment: Try what @Nick and I suggested together, I think that would get you what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @casraf yes I was testing it and it is ok combined with your suggestion about the length. to use .length() am I supposed to first parse originalORder with parseJson?

Comment: when you print `originalData`, do you get a string or a parsed object? If it's the first, then use `JSON.parse(originalData)`

Answer (score 0):

`originalOrder` is an object and for this reason, to get the number of keys (i.e., "the length of the object"), you need:

```js
Object.keys(originalOrder).length
```

---

To add a key with the value of the var `toAppend` you need to write:

```js
originalOrder[toAppend] = lunghezza
```

Comment: thanks, it is exactly what we were talking about in comments already.

Answer (score 0):

To use variable value as a key to an object you can use the square bracket in javascript.

```
const obj = {
   "hello": "world"
};
const key = "value";
obj[key] = "any value";
console.log(obj)
```

will print

```
{
   "hello": "world",
   "value": "any value"
}
```

Also, you can't use `length` properties on an object. However, you can get list of keys of an object, then get the length.

```
console.log(Object.keys(obj).length);
```

will print

```
2
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks, it is exactly what we were talking about in comments to the question already